# TVOUT With iOS in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

I am using iOS 5 with XCode 4.2

The iOS simulator has the function to turn on/simulate the TV-Out, then the simulator open and a seperate window for the TV out starts, but always in portrait mode, if i switch to landscape the window for the TV-Out disappears.

How do I Open the app in Landscape mode both in Simulator and TV-Out screen?